# ansible inventory を指定しなかった場合はどこから読み込む？

Tags: ansible

ansible-playbook は、 inventory を指定しなかった場合でも、何かしらの設定を読み込んで、実行できていることに気が付きました。
このデフォルトの設定を変更したいと考えています。

#### 質問:

Ansible に inventory を指定しなかった場合、どこの設定から inventory 情報を読み込むのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

デフォルトは /etc/ansible/hosts になります。

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html